# TensorFlow multi-GPU InvalidArgumentError : cifar10_multi_gpu.py

Tags: linux, tensorflow, gpu

I try to train my models with multi-GPUS. So I run the cifar10_multi_gpu.py (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) .

### **1. My location:**

---

OS Platform : Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64

TensorFlow installed : pip install --upgrade ./tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

Python version: Python 3.5.2

CUDA/cuDNN version: cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run  / cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1.tgz

### **2. GPU setup is correct**

> import tensorflow as tf
>
> with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
>
> ```
>      a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], shape=[3], name='a')
>
>      b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], shape=[3], name='b')
> ```
>
> with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
>
> ```
>      c = a + b
> ```
>
> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
>
> sess.run(c)
>
> add: (Add): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1 I
>
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] add:
>   (Add)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1 b: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 I
>
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] b:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 a: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 I
>
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] a:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
>
> array([ 2.,  4.,  6.], dtype=float32)

### 3. InvalidArgumentError: python cifar10_multi_gpu.py

> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:669] Ignoring device
>   specification /GPU:0 for node 'tower_0/fifo_queue_Dequeue' because the
>   input edge from 'prefetch_queue/fifo_queue' is a reference connection
>   and already has a device field set to /CPU:0
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1022, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)
>
> File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1000, in _run_fn
>       self._extend_graph()
>
> File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1049, in _extend_graph
>       self._session, graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
>
> File "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in
>   **exit**
>       next(self.gen)
>
> File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py",
>   line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
>       pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
>
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.**InvalidArgumentError**:
>   Cannot assign a device to node 'tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss_1':
>   Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0'
>   because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
>
> [[Node: tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss_1 =
>   ScalarSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/device:GPU:0"](tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss_1/tags, tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss)]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py", line 280, in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 44, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>
> File "cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py", line 276, in main
>       train()
>
> File "cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py", line 237, in train
>       sess.run(init)
>
> File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 767, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>
> File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 965, in _run
>       feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
>
> File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1015, in _do_run
>       target_list, options, run_metadata)
>
> File
>   "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1035, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.**InvalidArgumentError**:
>   Cannot assign a device to node 'tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss_1':
>   Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0'
>   because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
>
> [[Node: tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss_1 =
>   ScalarSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/device:GPU:0"](tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss_1/tags, tower_0/softmax_linear/weight_loss)]]

I try many solutions but failed. Thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you're hitting problems! I checked with one of the original authors of that script, and here was his response:

It looks like the device placement is not working well.

- According to the author's test, he checked to see that he can access "cpu:0" and "gpu:1" but he never checked "gpu:0". I would check that.
- The author should also set allow_soft_placement=True in the SessionConfig to allow for relaxed device placement.

Comment: Hi , Pete Warden ,thanks very much. Then about your response:

Comment: **Firstly**,  the script will run with cpu  if allow_soft_placement is True. But my task can not run with cpu , because cpu is too slow, it will take about several weeks . **secondly**  I don't understand that " he can access "cpu:0" and "gpu:1" but he never checked "gpu:0 " ,  I have four GPUS in my machine. I set  "tf.device('/gpu:1')" , it still falied.

Comment: **otherwise**, Can you recommend some distributed GPUS examples which can run  successfully for me. Thanks very much.